# Is there a difference between "depressive" and "depressing"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, collocation

Is news *depressing* or *depressive*? In what situations would you use these two words?

According to dicionary.com:

> depressive - tending to depress
>
> depressing - serving to depress; inducing a state of depression

That's why I'm asking. Those 2 explanations are very similar. Perhaps it's the difference is in intention?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What does a dictionary tell you about the words? Please don't ask people to re-present to you the basic research you have already done. You may want to read the answer to a [related Meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/asking-questions-about-synonyms) on how to ask about word differences and similarities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depressive mood and depressing scene.

The state of being depressed is *depressive*, but things that provoke depression are *depressing*.

> I'm depressed.
>
> I'm in a depressive mood.
>
> I've seen a depressing video.

Comment: I'm IN a depressive mood. Although I prefer *In a depressed mood* than *depressive mood*.

Answer (score 1):

"Depressive" can be an adjective or a noun; as an adjective I've only ever seen it in the phrase "depressive disorder".

As a noun, "depressive" can mean:

- some intangible thing that is depressing (such as news)
- a substance that has the effect of depressing mood or function: alcohol is a well-known depressive
- a person who suffers from depression

Comment: Psychiatrists use it to describe symptoms and states of depression: "depressive symptoms" and "a depressive episode" as well as, e.g., MDD (major depressive disorder). Using it to  mean "a person who suffers from depression" is no longer PC in the biomed field, but psychiatrists don't much care about that.